# Instrumentate a distant java application via javassist+javaagent+jmx

Tags: java, jmx, instrumentation, javassist, javaagents

Actually i want to developpe a java application witch should instrumentate another java application witch i don't have its source code..

I tried to create an agent and attach it to the jvm.. then i created an mbean and tried to connect to it.. it works when i try to instrumentate a class in my project.. but i don't know how could i instrument a distant application with my application..

here is my code: `https://github.com/ammouna8ammouna/Monitoring.git`

i am really new at the instrumentation world and i really need help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the processID of the VM that you are targeting you can attach your agent using

> com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine

For example if you have pid, the path of your JAR target and the loader that handle the JAR you can try something like this:

```
private static void attach(String pid, String jarPath,
        ClassLoader toolLoader) throws Exception {
    Class<?> attacherLib = toolLoader.loadClass("com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine");
    Class<?> string = toolLoader.loadClass("java.lang.String");

    Method attach = attacherLib.getMethod("attach", string);

    Object instance = attach.invoke(null, pid);

    Method loadAgent = attacherLib.getMethod("loadAgent", string, string);
    loadAgent.invoke(instance, jarFilePath, "");

    Method detach = attacherLib.getMethod("detach");
    detach.invoke(instance);
}
```

Let me know if it's clear or you need other help.